How to use docker for hot-reload during development in ASP.NET Core
I am developing a web app using ASP.NET Core. My tech stack for this project is: C#, Razor pages, .NET Core and EF Core (database).
This project has been my first run in with docker and I have been struggling to make it work with all of the specifications I need. My application is split into three parts, my main web app (UI and backend), email service (running on the side of the main app) and a database.
I have tried many different ways to make my docker setup, but I cannot seem to make everything work, I don't know if there is something wrong with the way I handle volumes or if there is some other issue, never the less I have either been facing the issue where hot reload does not work. Or if it has worked, my using statements and package references have been causing a load of errors after running a docker-compose up --build type of command.
This is the general file tree for my project (DDD focused):
├── CampusEats.md
├── CampusEats.sln
├── docker
│  ├── email-service.dockerfile
│  ├── entrypoint.dev.sh
│  └── webapp.dockerfile
├── docker-compose.dev.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── GroupProject.md
├── README.md
├── src
│  ├── Application
│  ├── Domain
│  ├── Email
│  ├── email-service
│  ├── Infrastructure
│  ├── SharedKernel
│  ├── WebApp
│  └── webapp
└── tests
   ├── EmailService.Tests
   └── WebApp.Tests

These are the docker files I am questioning:
docker-compose.dev.yml:
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/webapp.dockerfile
      target: development
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src:rw
    tmpfs:
      - /src/WebApp/bin:exec,mode=777
      - /src/WebApp/obj:exec,mode=777
      - /src/Application/bin:exec,mode=777
      - /src/Application/obj:exec,mode=777
      - /src/Domain/bin:exec,mode=777
      - /src/Domain/obj:exec,mode=777
      - /src/Infrastructure/bin:exec,mode=777
      - /src/Infrastructure/obj:exec,mode=777
      - /src/SharedKernel/bin:exec,mode=777
      - /src/SharedKernel/obj:exec,mode=777
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=db;Database=CampusEats;User=sa;Password=YourStrong!Password;TrustServerCertificate=True
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
      - DOTNET_WATCH_RESTART_ON_RUDE_EDIT=1
      - DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_MSBUILD_INCREMENTALISM=1
      - DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_LAUNCH_BROWSER=1
      - ASPNETCORE_STATICWEBASSETS__ENABLED=true
    depends_on:
      - db

  email-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/email-service.dockerfile
      target: development
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src:rw
    tmpfs:
      - /src/Email/bin:exec,mode=777
      - /src/Email/obj:exec,mode=777
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=db;Database=CampusEats;User=sa;Password=YourStrong!Password;TrustServerCertificate=True
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
      - DOTNET_WATCH_RESTART_ON_RUDE_EDIT=1
      - DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_MSBUILD_INCREMENTALISM=1
      - DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_LAUNCH_BROWSER=1
      - Logging__LogLevel__Default=Warning
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong!Password
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - sqldata:/var/opt/mssql

volumes:
  sqldata:

email-service.dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

WORKDIR /app

# First copy the solution file from root
COPY *.sln ./

# Create directories and copy project files
COPY src/WebApp/*.csproj src/WebApp/
COPY src/Application/*.csproj src/Application/
COPY src/Domain/*.csproj src/Domain/
COPY src/Infrastructure/*.csproj src/Infrastructure/
COPY src/SharedKernel/*.csproj src/SharedKernel/
COPY src/Email/*.csproj src/Email/

# Now restore packages
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else
COPY src/ src/

FROM build AS development
WORKDIR /app/src/Email
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--no-restore"]

# Production stage
FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish "src/Email/Email.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Email.dll"]

webapp.dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

WORKDIR /app

# First copy the solution file from root
COPY *.sln ./

# Create directories and copy project files
COPY src/WebApp/*.csproj src/WebApp/
COPY src/Application/*.csproj src/Application/
COPY src/Domain/*.csproj src/Domain/
COPY src/Infrastructure/*.csproj src/Infrastructure/
COPY src/SharedKernel/*.csproj src/SharedKernel/
COPY src/Email/*.csproj src/Email/

# Now restore packages
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else
COPY src/ src/

FROM build AS development
WORKDIR /app/src/WebApp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--no-restore"]

# Production stage
FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish "src/WebApp/WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]

At the moment with these files I am able to execute this command:
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up

And the only thing that does not work is my hot reload.
If someone here is good with docker, and maybe could see what the issue is with my docker setup, please enlighten me so I can fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.
